# Returning a result from a function after a promise resolves

Tags: javascript, rsvp.js

So I have to pass a simple boolean to a library. In order to get the value to return I have to evaluate the resolution of a promise(it makes a asynchronous call). So I have something like this:

```
import {funcThatReturnsPromise} from 'some-module';

function someFunc(someParam) {
   funcThatReturnsPromise(someParam).then(theResult => someOtherFunc(theResult));
} 

function someOtherFunc(someParam) {
   ....
   return true; // do some things and return a bool
}
```

The problem is that this returns a promise, not the bool. I can't (without forking a third party project) modify the calling code to handle a promise rather than a bool. I know the whole point of promises is to be able to handle asynchronous calls without nesting but in this case I need to handle things synchronously. I'm not sure how to do that. I've looked through the docs but I'm not seeing a way to do this. Could anyone point me in the right direction here?

Comment: A bit confused. You want your asynchronous call to be handle synchronously?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dealing with promises and asynchronous code can be confusing, but the key is to not overcomplicate it.  Don't try to un-invent the wheel, try  to understand where your code belongs within this structure.

If you want a section of code to run after the resolution of the promise, then it belongs in the `.then` callback.  It sounds like  you have half of your code in and half of your code out of that callback.

Expanding your code a little, I'm assuming you're trying to do something to the effect of;

```
function someFunc(someParam) {
   funcThatReturnsPromise(someParam).then(theResult => someOtherFunc(theResult));

   if(someOtherFunc(theResult)){
       alert('A RESULT!');
   }
} 

function someOtherFunc(someParam) {
   ....
   return true;
}
```

But what you should be doing is;

```
function someFunc(someParam) {
   funcThatReturnsPromise(someParam).then(theResult => {
       funcResult = someOtherFunc(theResult)
       if(funcResult){
           alert('A RESULT!')
       }
   });

} 

function someOtherFunc(someParam) {
   ....
   return true;
}
```